# Where to store Class Specific named constants in C++

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, constants

If you have a class that has some named constants, what is the best practive for storing the constants:

**Option 1:  Namespace in Class header**

So in my class header I will have:

```
class myClass
{
...
...
};

namespace NamedConstants
{
   const string Bucket = "Bucket";
}
```

**Option 2 Member Constants**

```
class MyClass {      // this goes in the class
private:                          // header file
  static const string Bucket;
  ...
};
```

... and in the class implementation file:

```
const string MyClass::Bucket = "Bucket";
```

---

I actually prefer Option 1, considering it to be cleaner: the variable name and value appear together.  Also, if you give the namespace a good name then it can make code more readable when you use constants:

```
TrafficLight::Green
```

Does anybody see any issue with this method over Option 2?

Comment: Are the string values class specific or global ?

Comment: @DumbCoder In my example they are specific to the class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put constant strings in C++: static class members or anonymous namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465546/where-to-put-constant-strings-in-c-static-class-members-or-anonymous-namespace)

Comment: Then the above link sure has the answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings are meant to be seen/used by users of the class, you wouldn't consider to make them `private` class members. So I conclude they are not meant to be seen/used by users of the class. But then it doesn't make sense to put them into the header at all.

If you put them into the class (or into namespace scope into the header), then all changes to their type and identifier will ***force clients to recompile*** their code.

If you put them ***into the class' implementation file***, they are a private detail of the class' implementation and changes to them only force recompilation of the class' implementation.
If you put them into an ***unnamed namespace***, they cannot collide with any other name:

```
namespace  {
  namespace NamedConstants
  {
     const string Bucket = "Bucket";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the Unnamed namespace not make it "more global" (for want of a better word)

Comment: It makes it private to that implementation file.

Comment: @David: Just so we don't misunderstand - that unnamed namespace would be in the class' __implementation__ file, not in its header.

Comment: Good stuff - that has answered my question - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 could lead to a separate string object for every file which includes the header. So it depends among others on how scarce your resources are.

Comment: However, if I put in CPP file I won't have this problem right?