# How to set a static member variable in the .cpp file using anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains a static member variable, I would like to initialize it using an anonymous namespace in the .cpp file just like what I saw in the link :[Where to put constant strings in C++: static class members or anonymous namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465546/where-to-put-constant-strings-in-c-static-class-members-or-anonymous-namespac)

But I am getting an error saying the current member rate cannot be defined in the scope. Why?

```
//A.h
namespace myclass
{
class A
{
   private:
      static double rate;
};
}


//A.cpp
namespace myclass
{
   namespace{
      double A::rate = 99.9;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: it's already a qualified member of a class:

```
//A.cpp
namespace myclass
{
   double A::rate = 99.9;
}
```

will do. The `static` will already stick, because of the declaration.

The confusion might be because `static` has different meanings:

- [What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c/1358796#1358796)

However, a `static` class member doesn't have anything to do with *visibility* (internal/external linkage). Instead it has to with *storage duration*.